# Before modifying the website code please make sure it is not used in index.php in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website

I am working on creating the multistore website when I editing the store configuration I got the below notification.

> Before modifying the website code please make sure it is not used in
>   index.php

what is it means?

Can you explain more with any examples if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Magento 2 with a sub-folder for each store view or website then your index.php file will often have code like

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'my_store_view_code'; 
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store'; // store or website
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

This tells Magento which store view to load. This is just a reminder to update this code if required.

Sometimes this is also done via a .htaccess file or similar depending on how you have chosen to configure your server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have 3 stores (fr, us and in) by default india, so how can I define? Can we have an example? If possible give me example both .htaccess and index.php

Comment: The [Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html) might be the best place to start. Without knowing your domain structure and server stack it's hard to advise.